# How to join data in MongoDB with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, synchronization

I have a system that stores data into a MongoDB database. Now I need to join part the data (dozen or so fields from each record) with large datasets stored in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. How to do this?

Both databases accumulate data constantly, and queries should always include fresh data (few minutes delay is ok). I'm expecting up to few thousand new or updated records per day on the MongoDB, and can't modify the SQL Server database.

One solution would be to sync new and updated data from MongoDB to a new database in the SQL Server, and then make the queries and joins there. Are there tools for syncing, should this be done on the application level, or somehow else? How to prepare for (rare) downtime in the SQL server that leads to inconsistency?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using both? Transitioning from one to the other..?

Comment: I have highly variable data (therefore MongoDB) and less-variable data collected for another project/system (where SQL server works better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would look at the direction of your data selection.  If you have a collection of given Mongo documents, and you want all the SQL Server data related to them, then if the collection isn't large and the criteria not complex, you just use a traditional loop.

On the other hand, if the join criteria is quite complex and coupled (i.e. across all Mongo documents and SQL Server rows and many fields and columns), only SQL Server is really going to perform that well (given appropriate indexes)

You could [mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport) to export the collection of changed documents to CSV, then do an upsert in SQL Server and then do your joins in native SQL.  Joins from the existing SQL database to another database on the same server are usually high performance - there's a little more overhead for security checks at the beginning,

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical task for ETL tool. You export data from both MongoDB & SQLServer, join them in the external tool and load them back or do whatever you need. As for the increments, depends whether you keep some sort of timestamp or anything allowing you to detect what is "new" since the last time. ETL tools these days are pretty fast so they can almost run in "transaction" mode.

You may look at CloverETL (for example). This blog post describes how to join two different MongoDB collections. For your case, one collection reading could be replaced with SQLServer table reading (advantage of ETL technology): http://blog.cloveretl.com/joining-multiple-mongodb-collections-in-cloveretl